# Angularjs Dynamic object updating

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I know one of the main functions of **angularjs** is to only update the `<body>` of your index or main route file.

But what I want to do is bootstrap my entire index with multiple sections and then only when navigating to different pages, it should update text, images etc.

Like shown in the index.html @ `<h1>Title: {{ Title }} or {{Title2}}</h1>`

**index.html**

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" ng-click="FP()">Start Bootstrap</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="hidden">
                            <a href="#page-top"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-scroll">
                            <a ng-click="FP()">First Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-scroll">
                            <a ng-click="SP()">Second Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-scroll">
                            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

 <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <h1>Title: {{ Title }} or {{Title2}}</h1>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Section One -->
    <section class="One" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

        </div>
    </section>
```

**First.html**

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
</div>
```

**Second.html**

```
<div ng-controller="SecondController">
    </div>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller("FirstController", function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.Title = "First";
});

app.controller("SecondController", function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.Title2 = "Second";
});
```

Comment: I guess you mean lazy loading? http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs

Comment: I figured it with this article actually thanks for it, post your answer and I will accept. @KobiCohen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested routing. [Nested States](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/12/using-nested-states-angularjs-ui-router/)

Answer (score 0):

How about ng-init?

It's a directive you can use within your app/controller scope (or root scope) at any event of page load/digest cycle. Within the directive you can execute data-updating functions.